# Carrying string labels of string variable after reshape

Tags: stata, reshape

I have dataset in Stata that looks like this

```
entityID    indicator    indicatordescr    indicatorvalue
1           gdp          Gross Domestic    100
1           pop          Population        15
1           area         Area              50
2           gdp          Gross Domestic    200
2           pop          Population        10
2           area         Area              300
```

and there is a one-to-one mapping between values of `indicator` and values of `indicatordescr`.

I want to reshape it to wide, i.e. to:

```
entityID    gdp     pop     area
1           100     15      50
2           200     10      300
```

where I would like `gdp` variable label to be "Gross Domestic", `pop` label "Population" and `area` "Area".

Unfortunately, as I understand, it is not possible to assign the value of `indicatordescr` as a value label of `indicator`, so the reshape can't transform these value labels into variable labels.

I have looked at this : [Bring value labels to variable labels when reshaping wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236066/bring-value-labels-to-variable-labels-when-reshaping-wide)

and this : http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/apply-labels-after-reshape/

but did not understand how to apply those to my case.

NB: the variable labeling after reshape must be done programatically, because `indicator` and `indicatordescr` have many values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"String labels" here is informal; Stata does not support value labels for string variables. However, what is wanted here is that the distinct values of a string variable become variable labels on reshaping.

Various work-arounds exist. Here's one: put the information in the variable name and then take it out again.

```
clear 
input entityID  str4 indicator   str14 indicatordescr    indicatorvalue
1           gdp          "Gross Domestic"    100
1           pop          "Population"        15
1           area         "Area"              50
2           gdp          "Gross Domestic"    200
2           pop          "Population"        10
2           area         "Area"              300
end 

gen what = indicator + "_"  + subinstr(indicatordescr, " ", "_", .)  
keep entityID what indicatorvalue 
reshape wide indicatorvalue , i(entityID) j(what) string 

foreach v of var indicator* {
    local V : subinstr local v "_" " ", all
    local new : word 1 of `V' 
    rename `v' `new'
    local V = substr("`V'", strpos("`V'", " ") + 1, .)
    label var `new' "`V'"
}

renpfix indicatorvalue
```

EDIT If the length of variable names bites, try another work-around:

```
clear 
input entityID  str4 indicator   str14 indicatordescr    indicatorvalue
1           gdp          "Gross Domestic"    100
1           pop          "Population"        15
1           area         "Area"              50
2           gdp          "Gross Domestic"    200
2           pop          "Population"        10
2           area         "Area"              300
end 

mata : sdata = uniqrows(st_sdata(., "indicator indicatordescr")) 
keep entityID indicator indicatorvalue 
reshape wide indicatorvalue , i(entityID) j(indicator) string 
renpfix indicatorvalue 
mata : for(i = 1; i <= rows(sdata); i++) stata("label var " + sdata[i, 1] + "  " + char(34) + sdata[i,2] + char(34))
end
```

LATER EDIT Although the above is called a work-around, it is a much better solution than the previous.

Comment: Thank you this does work. However, it is worth noting that doing so will prevent to carry over long labels. The algorithm above requires use variable names to carry variable+label information. And the reshape will only be successful if variable names are 32 characters or less. Is there a way that uses local macros in order to overcome that shortcoming?

Comment: Quick question: is it necessary to clear the mata or sdata from memory once the algorithm has run, and if so, how?

Comment: I can't see your dataset from here, but `sdata` is deliberately as _small_ a table of names and variable labels as you can have  (`uniqrows()` should ensure that). It does no harm to leave it there.

Comment: In this instance of my dataset, `sdata` will be quite small, but it mightn't be the case for everyone. And I do think it is good practice to erase potential memory hogs once they are not necessary anymore. How can I erase `sdata` and `mata` from memory?

Comment: How many variables do you have? Even 1000 wouldn't imply non-trivial storage demands. But sure, fair point, and a moment with the help tells you about `mata clear` and `mata drop`. The code for Mata is always there, regardless.

Comment: Thank you Nick. I am sorry my question sounded so stupid. I've never used mata before and for some reason, I thought it was a variable name... :§

Comment: That's OK. Mata is Stata's embedded programming language, which is very C-like and has strong support for matrices, hence the name. You are correct that arrays held in Mata necessarily consume (some) memory.